# Image integration returns error (CKfinder / CKeditor 5 / Laravel 5.7)

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm trying to add CKfinder to a website with the CKfinder package for Laravel. 
The attempt to insert an image ends with an alert and fails.

screenshots [here](http://www.geoarchi.net/docs/201901/screenshots.zip)

**Installation** (Laravel 5.7, updated)

inclusion of CKeditor 5 (inline) build without option

installation of CKfinder as specified here:
    https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package

basic implementation (authentication returns true)

inclusion of @include('ckfinder::setup') in the blade template

added ckfinder to the InlineEditor instance

```
        ckfinder: {
            uploadUrl: baseurl +'/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
            options: {
                resourceType: 'Images'
            }
        },
```

**Behaviour:**

OK:

The page is opened without error.

CKeditor is open, works normally and saves its text.

Image button calls the file selector.

The selected image is displayed in CKEditor div.

```
code:
<div class="ck5editable"">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4SY7RXhpZgAAT [...] AAAAAAAAAAAAA=">
    <figcaption class="ck-editor__editable ck-editor__nested-editable ck-placeholder" data-placeholder="Saisir la légende de l’image" contenteditable="true">
        <br data-cke-filler="true">
    </figcaption>
    <div class="ck-progress-bar" style="width:100%;"></div>
    </figure>
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: -9999px; width: 42px;">Objet image</div>
</div>
```

The selected image is correctly transmitted to the server (screenshot 3, apache log)

Image is saved in the intended location (screenshot 2, file tree)

BUT THEN:

An alert is displayed: "Sending failed file: <filename>."

After[OK], the image disappears from the editor and its html code

The console indicates two resources from XHR:

```
"blob": the image (screenshot safari-console-blob)
"connector": a script (screenshot safari-console-connector)


<script type="text/javascript">
        window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction("", "http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/siteh57\/public\/userfiles\/images\/[filename]", "");
</script>
```

I only see one weird thing: in this last script, the call to the function starts with an empty parameter.
Is there another mistake?

Does anyone have an idea or at least a lead?

Comment: Please try adding `responseType=json` parameter to `uploadUrl`, like:
`/ckfinder/connector?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json`

Comment: It works fine !  Thankk you very much for your help